# Issue when triggering jQuery animation having to double click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this animation that on click of a button makes a  div slide down and then up again. The  colour also changes. It works just the way I want however the first time you click it, it doesn't work you have to click twice to get it to respond.

Somebody suggested using…

event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation()

...however as Im not that great with js could someone advise where I would need to implement this in my existing code to solve the problem.

UPDATE*

Apologies as I mixed up my code  this is for a separate element in my site.

See the following fiddle… Notice how you have to tap/click twice to trigger it I only want to have to click once.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/46/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

   <div class="content-wrapper">
       <div class="padLeft">    
<h2>Project Title</h2>
<div class="crossRotate"> Open </div>
</div>     
<div class="padLeft">
<p>Paragraph Goes Here</p>
<h3>Play Video</h3>
</div>
</div>    

</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
z-index: 1;
}

.content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
background: red;
bottom: -90px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: bottom 1s;
-moz-transition: bottom 1s;
transition: bottom 1s;    
}

.crossRotate {
position: absolute;
background-color: blue;
z-index: 1;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
var clicked=true, animation=false;
$(".crossRotate").on('click', function(){
if(clicked)
{
    clicked=false;
    $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "-90px"});
}
else
{
    clicked=true;
    $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "0"});
}
});
```

Comment: It works for me from the first time clicking

Comment: Which browser(s)? OS? Works here on chrome win7

Comment: do you want to perform same task on double click?

Comment: Works for me, too and first there is no need to prevenDefault() since the clicked element is a div and thus has no default click behaviour like links and buttons do. Second there is no need to stopPropagation because there is no parent element with a similar event handler that your click would bubble up to. So these advices won't actually help

Comment: Apologies I've confused myself its happening on a different part I will edit the code

Comment: Updated my question and jsfiddle thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @user2498890 See my answer or athm's. Either negate your condition of the if statement by putting '!' before the 'clicked' variable or initialize it with false, which would be more consistent logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have understood your issue correctly.  You are using the clicked variable to work out whether the element has previously been clicked. On page load you are setting the clicked variable to true and therefore the client is setting bottom to -90px.  As the bottom is already set to -90px, nothing appears to happen.

I have updated the JSFiddle to set clicked to false, as this is surely the case on page load: http://jsfiddle.net/A8vG5/1/

```
var clicked=false;
$(".crossRotate").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "-90px"});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "0"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer After Your Edit**

It is working as you want i hope.

**jsfiddle javascript code**

```
var clicked=true;
$(".crossRotate").on('click', function(){
    if(!clicked)
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "-90px"});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "0"});
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle onClick Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/49/)

**Old answer**

For double click

```
$(".open-close").on('dblclick', function(){
```

[working Demo double click](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/41/)

For click

```
$(".open-close").on('click', function(){
```

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my code I want it to be single click but for some reason you have to double click to make it work its like there is a glitch or something.

Answer (score 0):

for work on double click please use

```
$(".open-close").on('dblclick', function(){
```

instead of

```
$(".open-close").on('click', function(){
```

NOTE: it only work for double click not for single click.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid bugs with multiple clicks, it's good to disable click event while animation is ongoing. About your first time, you mess with if; check this:

```
var clicked=true,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/43/

UPD: for your updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/54/

Comment: That's the same fiddle the OP posted. If you edit the fiddle click update to generate a new version.

Comment: thanks for your help I've updated my question, I had the wrong code for part of my site muddled I actually need help with this part.

Comment: @user2498890 - check my upd: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/54/ you messed with click value;

Answer (score 0):

You just got your if/else statement the wrong way around. Put:

```
if(!clicked)
```

and everything ist fine.